# Companion Stats/metrics to Go Alongside Rolling Regression Plot

Tags: regression, econometrics

Once you plot your coefficients in beta space over time (either as sum of coefficients or univariate), assuming you have a companion F-statistic joint significance plot, these alone are useful to see correlation and perhaps structural breaks or changes at each window over time. But aside from just glancing at such plots, are there any conventional statistics to go alongside them? I was thinking something like the following:

- area under curve
- percentage when β < 0 and/or percentage β > 0

To me that would be useful, but I want to keep in mind the general econometric reading audience as well. I already have the really basic stuff like, number of samples, r-squared, window size, ect, but are there other metrics, perhaps of more computational nature, specific and/or relevant to a rolling regression coefficient plot?